# how to use face_detector with kinect

Tags: kinect, ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the [face_detector](http://wiki.ros.org/face_detector) package to detect humans in a scene. When i try to the run the launch file face_detect.rgbd.launch it's not detecting face and nothing is published on the topic face_detector/faces_cloud.
any help here would be great.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202015/how-to-use-face_detector-with-kinect/) by [akhil](https://answers.ros.org/users/2787/akhil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2015-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Be sure to adjust topic names in a launch file you use. See [the changes on wiki recently added](http://wiki.ros.org/face_detector#Example_Usage), and [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/210751/face_detector-not-detecting-with-rgbd-camera/?answer=216920#post-id-216920) as a working example.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0